# Como solucionar el error illegal start of expression

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo este error en NetBeans:

> illegal start of expression

Intento ejecutar un código para crear una tabla en una Base de Datos, NetBeans me marca el error justo en el `String` para crear la taba.

Mis líneas de código son las siguientes:

```
public class Scripts {
public static void main (String args[]){    

public static String DB_TABLES[] = {"CREATE TABLE ARCHIVO(" +
                                    "ID INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                                    "NOMBRE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL," +
                                    "AREA VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL," +
                                    "ESTATUS VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL)"};
public static String DB_PK[] = {"ALTER TABLE ARCHIVO ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)"};    
// Llaves foraneas
public static String DB_FK[] = {};           }
```

Comment: Puede ser porque estas declarando variables públicas dentro del metodo, puedes revisar [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24562950/11685866) de SO en ingles

Comment: tu variable `DB_TABLES` no puede ser public static dentro de un metodo, podria solo si es miembro directamente de la clase

Comment: Si revisé la pregunta @Arreguin92, solo que no lo entendí muy bien, podrías darme mas detalles ?

Comment: A grandes rasgos, como bien dice @IgmerRodriguez las variables que tienes dentro de tu método main no pueden ser declaradas public, protected o private, quita el modificador de acceso `public` a tus variables `DB_TABLES, DB_PK y DB_FK`

Answer (score 3):

Todas las variables dentro de un método no pueden tener Modificadores de acceso, es decir, `Public` - `Private` - `Protected`, directamente se pone el tipo de dato y el nombre del mismo (Ejemplo: `int id`), para que funcione correctamente debería de ser:

```
public class Scripts {
public static void main (String args[]){    

String DB_TABLES[] = {"CREATE TABLE ARCHIVO(" +
                                    "ID INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                                    "NOMBRE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL," +
                                    "AREA VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL," +
                                    "ESTATUS VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL)"};
String DB_PK[] = {"ALTER TABLE ARCHIVO ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)"};    
// Llaves foraneas
static String DB_FK[] = {};
```

Por otro lado, si es que quisieras dejar las variables públicas y estáticas, debes de declararla a nivel de clase, no de método, es decir:

```
public class Scripts {
//variables ubicadas a nivel de clase
public static String DB_TABLES[] = {"CREATE TABLE ARCHIVO(" +
                                    "ID INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                                    "NOMBRE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL," +
                                    "AREA VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL," +
                                    "ESTATUS VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL)"};
public static String DB_PK[] = {"ALTER TABLE ARCHIVO ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)"};    
// Llaves foraneas
public static String DB_FK[] = {};           
//método main
public static void main (String args[]){    
    //TODO
}
```